# Are line feeds allowed in JSON strings?

Tags: json, xml, soa, osb

I need to send XML inside a JSON for my REST OSB 12c Proxy as follow:

```
{
    "login": "jstein",
    "identityContext": "jazn.com",
    "taskId": "string",
    "payload": {
        "any_0": {
            "any_01": "<afastamento xmlns:ns1='http: //www.tjsc.jus.br/soa/schemas/comagis/AfastamentoMagistrado' xsi:type='def: AfastamentoMagistradoType' xmlns:xsi='http: //www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='http: //xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/workflow/task'>
          <ns1:Magistrado>719</ns1:Magistrado>
          <ns1:Status>Inicial</ns1:Status>
          <ns1:Vaga>8770</ns1:Vaga>
          <ns1:Tipo>Licenca Nojo</ns1:Tipo>
          <ns1:PeriodoReferencia/>
          <ns1:DataInicialSolicitada>2015-10-10</ns1:DataInicialSolicitada>
          <ns1:DataFinalSolicitada>2015-11-05</ns1:DataFinalSolicitada>
  </afastamento>"
        }
    },
    "outcome": "Start"
}
```

The OSB 12c send me back the error:

> ```
>  "errorMessage" : "ORABPEL-15235\n\nTranslation Failure.\nFailed to translate
>  JSON to XML. org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Illegal unquoted
>  character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be
>  included in string value\n at [Source: java.io.BufferedReader@7db921c7; line:
>  7, column: 619]\nThe incoming data does not conform to the NXSD schema. Please correct the problem.\n"
> ```

I am testing my JSON request at JSONLint, and it always gives me the error about start a String with `<`:

> ```
> Parse error on line 7:
> "any_01": "<afastamento xmlns:
> -----------^
> Expecting 'STRING, 'NUMBER, 'NULL', 'TRUE', FALSE', '{', '['
> ```

Comment: Please read [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) an answer if you've been helped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**No**, literal line feeds (`CTRL-CHAR, code 10`) and newlines are control characters that are [**not allowed**](http://json.org/) within a JSON string:

[image]

XML does not require the line feeds between elements.  You can simply remove them, changing your multi-line XML document to an equivalent single-line XML document that will be able to be passed as a JSON string without problem.  Or, you may want to consider escaping the line feeds `\n`, or more generally, escaping the entire string:

- [How should I escape strings in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3020094/290085) [Java]
- [In C# how to encode XML to output it inside JSON in the JavaScript
  part of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6142875/290085)

Comment: Thank you kjhughes! With thes schema I solved my problem usinig scaped XML