# How to validate JSON Payload with Multiple lines in JAVA

Tags: java, rest, servlets, filter

```
{
    "name":"tarun",
    "Address":"abcdef

                    ghijkl"
}
```

I have extracted the payload from request body and trying to validate it using Mapper object. But it is throwing jsonparseexception.

Comment: Your problem might come from the fact that "literal line feeds and newlines are control characters that are not allowed within a JSON string (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566169/are-line-feeds-allowed-in-json-strings)". You might have to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved.I have removed the line using string replace method from the string JSON and then passed it to mapper object.